# Add block parameters to custom html block

Tags: mobirise

So in mobirise `4.0.15` I have noticed that supplied template blocks have "block parameters" enabled, but custom html blocks do not.

Looking at the source, I can see that the parameter properties which flow into sass are defined within `<mbr-parameters>`.

However copy and pasting `<mbr-parameters>` into a custom html block does not enable "block parameters" for some reason.

So how can I enable block parameters for a custom html block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that if add one of the **supplied templates**, then replace everything with my own custom html, the block parameters remain enabled which then allow me to write my own custom block parameters which is pretty cool.

I have contacted the devs asking if whether there is a better approach than this workaround, but at least this will achieve the desired results in the meantime (I will update this post once I have a reply).

An example:

```
<mbr-parameters>
<!-- Block parameters controls (Blue "Gear" panel) -->
    <input inline type="range" title="Margin Top" name="marginTop" min="0" max="8" step="1" value="6">
    <input inline type="range" title="Margin Bottom" name="marginBottom" min="0" max="8" step="1" value="6">
<!-- End block parameters -->
</mbr-parameters>
```

And then in my css:

```
margin-top: (@marginTop* 15px);
margin-bottom: (@marginBottom* 15px);
```